# ¿Como puedo setear una fecha de nacimiento al año actual con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este formato de fecha en la base de datos, en un campo `birth` YYYY-MM-DD y este código, necesito que transforme el año de `birth` a 2018

```
renderBirthday() {

      this.persons.forEach(function (data) {  
      const render = {
        className: 'birthday',
        event_id: data.id,
        title: data.name + '  ' + data.last_name + '   ' ,
        start: data.birth,
        textColor: 'black',
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      };
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', render, true);
    })
  },`
```

Answer (score 0):

El año actual se obtiene asi:

```
var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
```

En tu caso, a partir de la fecha que data.birth, creamos una nueva, con año actual, mas el mes y el dia de data.birth

```
 this.persons.forEach(function (data) {  

  data.birth = new Date((new Date).getFullYear(),data.birth.getMonth(),data.birth.getDate() +1);
      const render = {
```

En el caso que te pida la fecha formateada

usamos la siguiente función

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

y la implementamos

```
data.birth = formatDate(Date((new Date).getFullYear(),data.birth.getMonth(),data.birth.getDate() +1));
          const render = {
```

fuente formato : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero no está solucionando mi problema, necesito que birth = yyyy-MM-dd sea igual a 2018-MM-dd, así en el calendario me muestra los cumpleaños en el año actual aunque sean de 1990 etc, gracias

Comment: Alli modifique la respuesta